# How to scan through all "else if" conditions - C

Tags: c, arrays, conditional-statements

For my C assignment I'm required to input a donation amount, input requests, and fulfill requests. Basically I have an array named donType[i] with i ranging from 0 to 4. donType[0] represents protein requests, donType[1] represents dairy requests, dontype[2] represents grain requests, and so on as you will see in my code. If any donation type has an inventory of 0 (meaning no donations were added to the value of the array) then I want it to print "type donations cannot be fulfilled" where type represents the type of food (protein, dairy, grains, etc). If I leave all of the inventories set to 0, it will only print "Protein requests cannot be fulfilled" where it should print all the requests as not being able to be fulfilled. Here's a portion of my code:

```
        if (donType[0] == 0) 
            printf("Protein requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
        else if (donType[1] == 0)
            printf("Dairy requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
        else if(donType[2] == 0)
            printf("Grain requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
        else if (donType[3] == 0)
            printf("Vegetable requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
        else if (donType[4] == 0)
            printf("Fruit requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
```

So it stops after it scans that donType[0] is equal to 0. How can I make my code continue to scan through the else if statements? Keep in mind I'm new to this stuff so I don't need any complex answer. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might want to read about the `if` statement and how it works. Not clear what your problem is. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Take out all the `else`

Comment: The braces around the body of the `if` prevent the code compiling (the first `else` doesn't have an `if` to match).  You should probably be using a loop instead of writing out almost the same code 5 times.  You could have an array of donation type names: `char *donTypeName[] = { "Protein", "Dairy", "Grain", "Vegetable", "Fruit" };` and `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { if (donType[i] == 0) printf("%s requests cannot be fulfilled\n", donTypeName[i]); }` or thereabouts.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I accidentally added braces there (not sure why). I corrected the issue in the post. I'll also re-write my code with the loop like you recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions are not mutually exclusive, so just remove the `else` keyword so that they're all independent `if` statements.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?  It's short but it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to substitute the **else if** statements for **if** statements

```
if (donType[0] == 0) 
    printf("Protein requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
if (donType[1] == 0)
    printf("Dairy requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
if(donType[2] == 0)
    printf("Grain requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
if (donType[3] == 0)
    printf("Vegetable requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
if (donType[4] == 0)
    printf("Fruit requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed.

Comment: He needs to substitute `else` statements for the `else if` statements actually. You have it back to front.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely natural that your code stops once a condition is met. in c++ when the  **if** condition is met it skip the **else** statement.

**else if** is basically an **else** statement that you can use repeatedly.

In your case to check all conditions you need to replace the **else if** statement with a simple **if** statement.

```
     if (donType[0] == 0) 
        printf("Protein requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
     if (donType[1] == 0)
        printf("Dairy requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
     if(donType[2] == 0)
        printf("Grain requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
     if (donType[3] == 0)
        printf("Vegetable requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
     if (donType[4] == 0)
        printf("Fruit requests cannot be fulfilled.\n");
```

Comment: Note that this question is tagged [tag:c] and not [tag:c++].

Comment: There should not be `{ }` where you have it

Answer (score 0):

After having met the true condition for first if statement the else portion is skipped. Remove else as all the conditions are independent from one another. In your case as the first if statement evaluate s to true, rest of the statements are skipped because of else.